# Invoke constructor on reflected type with callback of said type

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class X with some constructor that has a callback, where the callback passes back the instance of X:

```
class X
{
    public X(Action<X> callback) { ... }
}
```

Since I don't have access to the class `X` (it's internal in another assembly), I'm using reflection to obtain the type and the constructor, so far so good. And don't worry, something like this won't be used in production, it's just for testing purposes.

However, how can I type the callback if I don't have access to `X` statically? An `Action<object>` gives casting errors on invocation (understandably). Note I don't actually care about the `X` type, an object representation is fine.

Thanks

Edit: By request, here's the invocation context:

```
    public static object CreateCallbackType(Action<object> onNewData)
    {
        if (s_staticType == null)
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.Load("<>");
            var types = assembly.GetTypes();

            foreach (var t in types)
            {
                if (t.Name == "<X>")
                {
                    s_staticType = t;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (s_staticType == null)
                return null;
        }

        return Activator.CreateInstance(s_staticType, onNewData);
    }
```

Comment: Why callback with an instance of `X` when the constructor returns that anyway? And show the code you are using to create it, how else are we supposed to know what you are doing? Provide a [MCVE].

Comment: As you don´t know `X` in the outside I can´t imagine why anyone would use a callback that expects an instance of `X` which he can´t acess in any way at all.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I can't show the code to create it - that's the very question... ?

The callback is called back asynchronously and is multiplexed between a lot of instances on different threads, so the X object is used for identity and mapping (but has other features I don't care about).

Comment: @Shaggi `I'm using reflection to obtain the type and the constructor, so far so good.` You are attempting to create an instance of the `X` as you commented. Show that code.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, The original authors intention was for the callback to  be used only inside his own assembly; where X is accessible

Comment: This question reduces down to: *"How to instantiate an Action<X> where X is protected?"*

Comment: @BuhBuh Yes, probably.

Answer (score 2):

The `Action<T>` delegate is contravariant, so you can simply:

```
public static void Callback(object par)
{
    Console.WriteLine(par.ToString());
}
```

In this case contravariant means that instead of passing an `Action<X>` you can pass an `Action<anybaseclassofX>`, so clearly an `Action<object>` is ok.

and then:

```
var res = constructor.Invoke(new object[] { (Action<object>)Callback });
```

or

```
var res = Activator.CreateInstance(type, (Action<object>)Callback);
```

Note that contravariance is only for reference types: `X` must be a `class`, not a `struct`!

Comment: But in this case, it is the other way around: `X` invokes the typed callback (that receives the `X` input parameter), and the client of the interface has the `Action<object>` .. ? I would have assumed contravariance would have worked anyway, but as said I'm getting casting errors when invoking the constructor directly (through a ConstructorInfo) or mismatch error when using Activator.CreateInstance

Comment: @Shaggi Using the immortal phrase: it works on my computer (and on Ideone): https://ideone.com/TCWSoV